# Path finding between points in a 2d array

Tags: java, matrix, path-finding

So in my Java project we are working on a robot that draws a png, and it is my job to make the order of points so i basically have to draw a path from a 2d array of points.

The input i get is a 2d int[][] array width a max width and max height. The array contains points with a value of 1 and the white spaces have a 0 as value.
I am not a verry experienced programmer but i have tried to make something myself. But every source i try to look at it seems very complicated and i dont really have the interest or time to learn what it all means.

So if somebody already has solved this problem or has a simple solution please let me know.
Most path finding algorithms have obstacles or specific nodes, but this is pretty redundant for me.

This is how i would imagine the class would look

```
public class Path {
    public int maxWidth;
    public int maxHeight;
    
    public Path(int maxWidth, int maxHeight, int[][] matrix){
        this.maxHeight = maxHeight;
        this.maxWidth = maxWidth;
        int[][] result = getOrdererdMatrix(matrix);
    }
    
    public int[][] getOrdererdMatrix(int[][] matrix){
        //order points
        return null;
    }
    
    public void drawCanvas(int width, int height, int[][] matrix){
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                System.out.printf(String.valueOf(matrix[x][y]));
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to make my own classes of "point" and "canvas" and then for every point in the canvas compare the distance to the other points and then add the next point with the shortest distance to an ordered array, i could get this to work however.

Comment: If somebody has an idea for a library that has this feature it would also work fine

Comment: "it is my job to make the order of points so i basically have to draw a path from a 2d array of points."
What are your constraints? Without constraint then you can visit the points in any order. Do you want to avoid crossing your path? Do you want to minimize the path length? If it's the latter then it's the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), which is NP-hard, which means no fast exact solution exist, however if you don't have too many points, then the exact solution should be fine for your case.

Comment: I want to minimize the path length, but the salesmen problem is more focused on having specific "roads" to travel along. And it could ofcourse be simplified, but i dont know how.

Comment: The "roads" are the segments of your path. You have a complete graph and there is an edge (road) between each pair of points, which is the euclidian distance between them

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is. Perhaps you could edit the question to show some small examples.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Exact_algorithms).

### Exact solutions

If you have a hard requirement to minimize the path length, then you have to use one of the [exact algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Exact_algorithms), for example [Held–Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm#Pseudocode%5B4%5D)

```
function algorithm TSP (G, n) is
    for k := 2 to n do
        g({k}, k) := d(1, k)
    end for

    for s := 2 to n−1 do
        for all S ⊆ {2, ..., n}, |S| = s do
            for all k ∈ S do
                g(S, k) := minm≠k,m∈S [g(S\{k}, m) + d(m, k)]
            end for
        end for
    end for

    opt := mink≠1 [g({2, 3, ..., n}, k) + d(k, 1)]
    return (opt)
end function
```

### Approximation solutions

If it's not a hard requirement, then you can have a look at one of the [approximation algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Heuristic_and_approximation_algorithms).

One easy to implement solution, is the bitonic tour, which is where you add a constraint that the path must go from left to right and then right to left, and find the minimum path under this constraint. You can find a Java implementation here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitonic-traveling-salesman-problem/